# How to import sf2 file to keyboard?

Tags: piano, keyboard, software, performing, sound

**How** to do so??
I have searched, but couldn't find ***any*** *relevant* information

Comment: What kind of keyboard?

Comment: sorry i forgot to clarify... An arranger (yamaha)

Comment: I think the exact model of keyboard would help.

Comment: @Feliks_WR please read [ask], take your time to create a *good* question and provide all required information. We cannot just guess what we don't know.

Comment: A bit of research suggests that it can’t be done. Sound fonts are meant for computers and not for keyboards. There might be Emu keyboards that could do it

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for mentioning the model of the keyboard, but please edit the question itself to include the necessary information, and if you can, get more specific about the model (it looks like maybe there are 7 or so "arrangers"?). Also, if the answer is simply going to be "you can't," you might get some better guidance if you explain *why* you want to do so; maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: SoundFont is EMU technology. On a matter of principle, Yamaha would never have used it. They wouldn't license 3rd party tech if they could find a way to a) patent their own or b) buy the company that held the patent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic answer without knowing the model of the keyboard:

- Find the manual
- Read the manual and search for information on importing samples
- If the keyboard supports importing samples, find the format that it supports. It's probably not SoundFont.
- Search the web for converting SoundFont to this format. After converting, follow the keyboard manual for importing them.

Answer (score 2):

Sf2 files are SoundFonts.  A set of samples which can be loaded into a suitable playback system.  The Creative Labs SoundBlaster cards which used to be a popular choice for computer music systems used them.  Today you're most likely to encounter them in the MuseScore notation program, though most sequencers support plugins that will play soundfonts.

You didn't find information in directly importing SoundFonts to your keyboard, because it's almost certain you can't.  (And if it could, instructions how to do it would be prominent in its manual.) However, you may be able to connect to a computer by MIDI and use the keyboard to play SoundFonts hosted by a suitable program on the computer.

You say you have an 'Arranger' keyboard.   It's very likely that all it can send over a MIDI connection are the actual notes you press.  Not the auto-accompaniment 'Arranger' stuff.

Comment: This is exactly how I did it with my old, early 1990's Roland keyboard. In the DAW the soundfont is select like a plugin for the midi track of the keyboard. The keyboard part should be generic midi connection, the soundfont details will be in the specific DAW application. FWIW, I could also set drum set plugins (not soundfonts) and then the keyboard auto-accompaniment drums patterns or the keyboard keys mapped to midi drums would play the sampled drum set.

Comment: Yes, some keyboards sendt everything they play over MIDI.   Many only send the actual keys you press.